# How to use jquery plugins in Vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, scrollbar

I am currently rewriting the code to Vue.js and I want to use some Jquery plugins, but I do not quite understand how to do it. For example i want to use plugin scrollbar: http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html#anchor

I understand that I have to initialize it something like this:

```
mounted() {
        if (process.client) {
            $(".product-page .product-filter-wr").scrollbar();
        }
    }
```

But for this to work, I need to insert the script connection in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollbar.js"></script>
```

Actually, this is the problem. I am using template syntax, how can I connect a script to a page?
How can I connect the plugin to the page correctly?

Comment: What are you using to build your code? Nuxt? Rollup? Webpack? Nothing?

Comment: @FitzFish webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to include the script at a precise moment of the execution (such as the mounted hook), I advise you to use a dynamic loading library, for example [loadjs](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs).

```js
var loadjs = require('loadjs'); // or load it using CDN

// ...

mounted() {
  if (process.client) {
    loadjs(['/jquery.js', '/jquery.scrollbar.js'], 'scrollbar');
    loadjs.ready('scrollbar', () => {
      $(".product-page .product-filter-wr").scrollbar();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
npm install jquery
```

after that, you need to import it

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

once its done use

```
mounted() {
        if (process.client) {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                $(".product-page .product-filter-wr").scrollbar();
             },500);
        }
    }
```

make sure jquery is present in your component.

Comment: But how i should Initialize scrollbar ?

Comment: @Alexander i would suggest use perfect scrollbar with vue js npm i perfect-scrollbar